# PDF file not getting deleted in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am very new to writing windows batch programmes.

I am trying to delete a pdf file in my batch programme. However the file is not getting deleted. I don't know what is wrong with this code. It works well when i try to delete a .txt file. I don't know how to trap the error also. It will be really helpful if you can guide me or redirect me to an appropriate forum.

This is the code I use:

```
echo Y | del \\file_path\filename.pdf
```

Comment: You run the batch in powershell? Did you tried to remove that file with powershell cmdlet?

Comment: @Cavalli. I dont know whether it is powershell or not. This is a file ending with .bat and we call it as a windows batch file. I write the code in text document and save it as .bat file. Sorry. I am very new to this and today is my first day in this work. Please advice me if I had posted the question in a wrong place.

Comment: @Arun - is the PDF file on your local machine, or is it on a mapped network drive?

Comment: @SomethingDark - it has been mapped to a drive. For that matter of fact, even the .txt files are in a network drive. That is deleting correctly with out any issues. only pdf files are creating issues. Thank you

Comment: @Arun I have updated my post, hope that it will be helpful

Comment: Is the PDF file write-protected? if so, use `del /F` to force deletion of read-only files; you could also add the `/Q` switch, so the won't be any prompts whether to delete files, so you could omit the `echo Y |` pipe...

Comment: @aschipfl - Thank you this has worked.

Comment: You're welcome! so the PDF files were read-only?

Comment: @aschipfl - Yes. they were read only. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it with powershell, if you get "access dined" just run your PS console as administrator. Here is the simple code:

```
$myfile = "C:\Myfile.pdf"

Get-Item -Path $myfile | Remove-Item -Force
```

Update:

You can also use this script to remove your file from a share:

```
$myfile = "\\server\share\myfile.pdf"

Get-Item -Path $myfile | Remove-Item -Force
```

You can also run this script from a batch file:

1. Save the script above somewhere on your local disk eg "c:\myscript.ps1"
2. Create a new batch file with this command:

   powershell.exe -Executionpolicy remotesigned -File c:\myscript.ps1

Where "c:\myscript.ps1" is the path to your powershell scipt

Comment: Thanks for the answer